# Please help with this mod_rewrite issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

This current system in place needs to allow periods (`.`) optionally inside of the rewrite condition.

For example: `/john.doe` should work, since we allow periods in our user names.

However when I add `.` or `\\.` or `[.]` to the following rewrite rule, it either gets stuck in an endless loop, having to restart apache2. Amazingly, the behaviour has changed and I am not sure why. Now it just appends the new string to the existing URL.

For example: `/john.doe` will become `/john.doe/?pg=user&username=john.doe`

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9_]+)$ /?pg=user&username=$1 [NC,PT]
```

I am going crazy trying to fix this, please help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work (I'm saying "should" as I do not know how your whole system is set up and what other redirects etc are in place -- I see you are using `PT` flag (maybe you are using aliases)):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\.]+)$ /index.php?pg=user&username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\.]+)$ /index.php?pg=user&username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I have specified the script file directly -- it's much more easier to write a rule if you know how it works behind.